# How do I style the backBarButtonItem title in a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to be able to change only the text color of the back button in the navigation bar.

As a work around, I can sort of do what I'm trying to do by creating a custom view and assigning it to `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, but it doesn't look very good and I also lose the swipe to pop ability.
[image]

Code for the above:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let originalImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BackButton")
    let scaledImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: originalImage.cgImage!, scale: 30, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)

    button.setImage(scaledImage, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("YourTitle", for: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.setTitleColor(.brown, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .blue

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

I also see things suggested like setting attributes of the back button via

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the look of the text, despite

```
print("Attributes: ", navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem?.titleTextAttributes(for: .normal) ?? "No attributes")
```

resulting in `Attributes:  ["NSColor": UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1]`.

I could set `tintColor` but that would change the color of the back icon in addition to the title.

So what's the best way to do what I want? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can style the back button by setting `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` in the previous view controller.

For example, in my case I had `TableViewController` and when you clicked on a cell, the app would transition to `ViewController`. In `TableViewController` I had

```
public func changeColor() {
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Anything", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.brown], for: .normal)

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

and then in `ViewController` I had

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as! TableViewController
    vc.changeColor()
    self.title = "hello very long title asdfasdfasfdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
}
```

As a result, pressing a button in `ViewController` would change the color of the title of its back button to brown.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure whether I understood you correctly. But try the below code. This will apply to all the bar button items of your app. Place this code where it is called only once though out app lifecycle. Like `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
let attribs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attribs, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Your solution would change the color for bar button items across the entire app. I just wanted to change the back button color in one view controller. See my answer.

Thanks anyway!